# append html file to another html file using jquery locally

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, jquery-load, jquery-get

I have tried to append a html file into a html file using the `$.get` method as well as `$.ajax` and `.load` methods. the actual issue is that the file does not append yet works when opened alone. could it be that the site is running from the computer and not a server? or is there something that needs to be declared in either the html files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Chrome it will not work until you upload it to the server or use a local server.

I like XAMPP

Open google chrome through `cmd prompt` with cmd:
[chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/load-and-ajax-not-working-on-google-chrome)
(P.S: untested.)

Comment: ill try in opera and firefox ;)

Comment: you've helped me once again bud...i wouldn't want to allow access file because the website i want is going to be a file to show some holiday pictures and shared to some family soo... :/ . thankyou though i would've been here for days figuring it.